# How to enable touch slide from one string to another for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

OK so I want to be able to enable touch slide also in my app. It's basically showing an xml screen that has a textview that changes every time someone goes to the next tip. It's a relationship tips app and I want them to be able to just touch and slide to the next tip besides just pressing next and previous.

```
public class RelationshipTipsActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

String facts[] = {"Coming soon",
        "Coming soon", };

TextView display, display1;
TextView counter;
Button begin;
Button next;
Button previous;
Button random;
Random myRandom;

int index = facts.length;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(starting.rt.R.layout.relationship);

    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    display1 = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Begin);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.tvResults);
    counter = (TextView) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.tvCounter);
    next = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Next);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Previous);
    random = (Button) findViewById(starting.rt.R.id.Random);

    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    random.setOnClickListener(this);
    // display.setOnTouchListener(this.gestureListener);
    myRandom = new Random();

    // gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    // gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    // public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // }

    // };
}



private void showDisplay() {
    display.setText(facts[index]);
    counter.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(facts.length));
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case starting.rt.R.id.Next:
        index++;
        if (index > facts.length - 1) {
            index = 0;
        }
        showDisplay();

        break;

    case starting.rt.R.id.Previous:
        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = facts.length - 1;
        }
        showDisplay();
        break;

    case starting.rt.R.id.Random:
        index = (myRandom.nextInt(facts.length) - 1);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = facts.length - 1;
        }
        showDisplay();
        break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you considered using a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)?

Comment: No, thanks for the suggestion, I just don't know how to implement correctly. I'm going to try.

Comment: I don't really know how to implement ViewPager